# Why am I getting Argument count mismatch with a simple movieclip creation?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I have this in my document class:

```
var newButton:silverButton = new silverButton("hello");
```

And this is silverButton:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class silverButton extends MovieClip {

        public function silverButton(hello:String) {
            btnTxt.text = hello;
        }
    }

}
```

The error I'm getting: ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on silverButton(). Expected 1, got 0.

Comment: You might be trying to instantiate the class elsewhere. For example, if you've instantiated the class from the UI directly, then you might get this error

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared does not reflect your problem, as the above should work well...

Are you linking the above class to a library item? In that case it might not get the constructor argument at all. You have to set it with other functions.

Also you may try setting the argument to be an optional parameter if the same class is to be initialized with & without default arguments. Something like :

```
public function silverButton(hello:String = "") {

       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have placed an instance of silverButton on the timeline (within the Flash IDE).

Also you might want to consider naming all your classes with a starting uppercase letter, and instance names with a lowercase which is the popular naming convention.

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class SilverButton extends MovieClip {

        public function SilverButton(hello:String) {
            btnTxt.text = hello;
        }
    }

}


var newButton:silverButton = new SilverButton("hello");
```